# Can't you use 'could be' instead of 'would be'?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> ✲ If you came tomorrow, [you *were* able to help with the flowers].
>   We can correct the apodosis by changing *were* to *would be*, but this change involves adding modal *would*.
>   (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p.107)

CGEL only says *were* needs to be changed to *would be*. Can't *could be* be used instead of *would be*? If it can, what is the semantic difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different ways of substituting *could* into this sentence.

- If you substitute *could* for *would* you change the meaning. With ***would*** be able to help the *would* expresses contingency, but is otherwise solidly predictive: if the condition is in fact met, you definitely **will** be able to help. *Could be able to*, on the other hand, introduces another layer of uncertainty. In this context, *could* is functionally equivalent to *might*; so what is said is that if the condition is in fact, there is only a **possibility** you will be able to help.
- Note however that *can* is equivalent to *be able to*. Consequently, you may substitute *could* not merely for *would* but for the entire verb construction *would be able to*:

  > If you came tomorrow you could help with the flowers.

  In strict logic, this would be equivalent to the original emendation *If you came tomorrow you would be able to help with the flowers*. In practise, however, it would employed differently: depending on context it might indicate either

  > an offer of a tempting opportunity: "I know you *love* arranging flowers, so if you came tomorrow we could put that in your hands!"
  >       or
  >   a hopeful request for needed assistance: "I know you're very busy, but I'd be oh-so-grateful if you could find the time to give me a hand with the flowers."

Context, context, context!